# CFSEARCH Solr Collection limitations

Tags: coldfusion, solr

I have migrated a Verity based CFSEARCH solution over to Solr based CFSEARCH solution and finding that Solr is not returning all results when searching against multiple collections.  I am going to work around this via running separate CFSEARCH calls and consolidating my results but wanted to know if a better work around exists that would allow things to work via just one CFSEARCH call.  Code that does not return the proper results is pretty simple:

```
<CFsearch NAME="EMCSearch"
    COLLECTION="apropos,certegy,cmco,conoco,contracts,corpbadge_pki,cust_train,delft_dc,documentation_help,dsvcs,grti,gts,infosys,mgmt_tools,pers,processes,scc,sd,slb,srv_desc,tips,voip,WAN_Work_Procedures,west"
        CRITERIA="#LCase(searchfor)#">
```

That returns a record count of 23 results.  If I however change things to this I get a combined record count of 76:

```
<cfset lstCols  = "apropos,certegy,cmco,conoco,contracts,corpbadge_pki,cust_train,delft_dc,documentation_help,dsvcs,grti,gts,infosys,mgmt_tools,pers,processes,scc,sd,slb,srv_desc,tips,voip,WAN_Work_Procedures,west" />
<cfloop list="#Variables.lstCols#" index="Col">
    <CFsearch NAME="EMCSearch"
        COLLECTION="#Col#"
        CRITERIA="#LCase(searchfor)#">
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I am afraid I can't help - however I do suggest not using CF9s inbuilt solr support using cfsearch. I would personally just use cfhttp and it's rest api (as I have heard the cf9 solr support can be flaky as you have seen).

Comment: I might do just that if the consolidated approach I took ends up having issues.  Our backup environment is still on CF6 w/Verity which is how we ended up noticing these differences in what is returned.

Comment: Agree with @Bigfellahull. Getting away from the CFINDEX/CFSEARCH is one of the best things you can do to improve your searching in CF. Use the "shards" parameter to search multiple Solr cores with CFHTTP. As an aside, the fact that Verity and Solr are returning different results does not necessarily imply a problem with searching multiple collections. CF's Solr implementation has some odd features, such as making searches on record titles case-sensitive.

Comment: One other note, the first and second searches are not logically the same. If there are records with duplicate IDs then the first search will return fewer records than the second.

Comment: Still one more note. You can check the results you get in ColdFusion vs. the results you get in Solr by going to http://localhost:8983/solr/<collection_name>/select?q=searchfor

Comment: Concatenating the results of each separate resultset was a fair enough solution.  If this would not have been on a pre-existing application then perhaps would have addressed things differently.

Comment: I'm trying to follow David Faber's advice, and I've hit a bit of a snag. Using CFHTTP does not give me the same fields as CFSEARCH does. CFSEARCH gives me all four custom fields, author, category, context, key, rank, score, size, summary, title, type, and URL. I'm not getting most of these with the CFHTTP code I'm trying to use. Is there a way to customize the returned data from CFHTTP? Thank you, ^_^